# Опишите кратко что делают данные C++ функции

Tags: c++builder, c++, функции

```
int f( int n )
{
if ( n <= 1 )
    return 0;
else
    return 1 + f( n / 10 );
}
```

и

```
int g( int n )
{
if ( n <= 0 )
    return 0;
else
    return 1 - ( n % 2 ) + g( n / 2 );
}
```

Мне понятно то, как будет выполняться каждая из функций с любыми входными данными и то, что они вернут в результате. Но не понятно само назначение данных функций, а похоже в задании требуется указать именно это. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

С первой более-менее понятно - она возвращает число цифр в записи числа, равного аргументу разделенному на два. Если бы там был бы не <=, а просто <, то она бы возвращала кол-во цифр в записи числа (для всех чисел больше 1).

А вот с второй не понятно,  так как не известно, что делает функция `foo`.

Comment: там тоже g()

Comment: что значит "число цифр в записи числа, равного аргументу разделенному на два". Допустим входной параметр = 10, функция вернет 2, а при записи числа 5 используется 1 цифра

Comment: при входном параметре 10, функция возвратит 1. Проверяем - 10 делим на два - 5, а в записи 5 - одна цифра.

Comment: Результаты выполнения функции при [0:75]. Причем, это видно устно
0 = 0
1 = 0
2 = 1
3 = 0
4 = 2
5 = 1
6 = 1
7 = 0
8 = 3
9 = 2
10 = 2
11 = 1
12 = 2
13 = 1
14 = 1
15 = 0
16 = 4
17 = 3
18 = 3
19 = 2
20 = 3
21 = 2
22 = 2
23 = 1
24 = 3
25 = 2
26 = 2
27 = 1
28 = 2
29 = 1
30 = 1
31 = 0
32 = 5
33 = 4
34 = 4
35 = 3
36 = 4
37 = 3
38 = 3
39 = 2
40 = 4
41 = 3
42 = 3
43 = 2
44 = 3
45 = 2
46 = 2
47 = 1
48 = 4
49 = 3
50 = 3
51 = 2
52 = 3
53 = 2
54 = 2
55 = 1
56 = 3
57 = 2
58 = 2
59 = 1
60 = 2
61 = 1
62 = 1
63 = 0
64 = 6
65 = 5
66 = 5
67 = 4
68 = 5
69 = 4
70 = 4
71 = 3
72 = 5
73 = 4
74 = 4
75 = 3

Comment: какой функции? я говорил о первой, а Вы пишете о второй.

Comment: а вторая функция - это кол-во нулей в двоичной записи числа больше 1. Проверка - 15 = 1111b - нет нулей, 0. 10 = 1010b = 2.

Answer (score 1):

Первая возвращает `floor(log10(5*n))`

Вторая - количество нулей в двоичной записи числа `n`
Как правильно заметил KoVadim, нужно сделать оговорку "для положительных чисел"

Comment: первое неверно. Например, при `n=15`. Второе - переписано у меня, но не совсем верно. К примеру, если `n=0`.

Comment: @KoVadim - спасибо за контрпример с n=15.  Поправил.  Ваш коммент по второй задаче я не видел, т.к. он был свёрнут.